# Google Calendar doesn't show yearly event on 29.Feb. = bug?

Tags: google-calendar

A friend of mine has his birthday on the 29.Feb. and I've created a repeating event in Google Calendar for this. Google Calendar shows this event on leap years but not on non-leap years (like next week!).

I had expected the calendar to move the event either to the day before or the day after (either direction can be argued), but *not showing the event at all* is a bug in my opinion.

Is there a way I can fix this?
Is this a known bug in Google Calendar? (Will it ever be fixed?)
How would *you* expect this to be handled?

Comment: Logically, the event only repeats every four years =)

Comment: @Gipsy, I agree in principle :) but my friend would be sad if I'd only congratulate him in leap years.

Comment: This may be a little low-tech, but why not set a reminder on the 28th?

Comment: Yes, that's another very good solution *because it's so simple I didn't even think of it!* But it doesn't answer the question itself.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Some one came up with a great solution that writes an event on your calendar on the 60th day of the year, equivalent to Feb 29th or Mar 1st dependent.

http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=1afbf0737d261d5c&hl=en

> You want an event that recurs on the 60th day of any year equivalent to Mar-1 or Feb-29 where applicable. I have done a bit of source code below. Just replace "Someone" with the name of the person you want, save as a .ics file type in notepad and upload to your calendar.
>
> BEGIN:VCALENDAR
> BEGIN:VEVENT
> DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20090301
> DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20090301
> RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYYEARDAY=60
> DESCRIPTION:
> LOCATION:
> SEQUENCE:0
> STATUS:CONFIRMED
> SUMMARY:Someone's Birthday
> TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
> END:VEVENT
> END:VCALENDAR

Hope this helps.

To import the ICS file: in the left-hand list of "My Calendars", click the "Settings" link, and then on the "Import Calendar" link.

Comment: 60th day -- what an awesome workaround!! I can confirm this works just fine: this year the event lands on 01.Mar. and next year on 29.Feb. = perfect!

Answer (score 7):

Here's an alternative solution that yields the last day of February (either the 28th or the 29th) instead:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120229
DTEND;VALUE=DATE:20120229
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;INTERVAL=1;BYMONTH=2;BYMONTHDAY=-1
DESCRIPTION:
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:Someone's Birthday
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Generally, this is more appropriate for birthdays, since in many jurisdictions, 29 February is legally just a simple extension of 28 February for the purposes of calculating anniversaries and other annual things.

Of course, you can celebrate the Leap Babies however you want in nonbissextile years; this is just another solution for those who prefer to keep it in February!

If this helps, you may wish to read more about the flexibility offered by [custom recurrence rules in the iCalendar specification](http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/rrule.html).